# Libraries for creating a 'stand alone' Web Service deployed as a single binary

Tags: web-services

I want to create a simple web service which I shall then make available to third parties to host. The third parties will want to host the service as part of their own systems be that Windows, Linux or Solaris. They will want the web service to be made available to them as a pre compiled binary which they can run without dependencies on further third party software other than the OS itself.

So I am looking for a library, preferably in C / C++, which I can use to create a stand alone web service. I don't want to buy, install configure and manage some Application Server middleware such as Web Sphere, nor do my customers. I am happy to have a RESTFUl service rather than using SOAP.

I'm sure there are more than options available each with their own pro's and con's. A comparison of the options would be fantastic.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at Webtoolkit (or 'wt'): [www.webtoolkit.eu](http://www.webtoolkit.eu)